# Why my probability function does not work?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I'd like to compute the following expression using Mathematica:

```
Probability[Cos[X1]+Cos[X2]<=0,{X1,X2}~UniformDistribution[{0,2*Pi}]]
```

`0` in here is just an example. I'm more interested in computing the probability for a generic expression of `x`:

```
Probability[Cos[X1]+Cos[X2]<=x,{X1,X2}~UniformDistribution[{0,2*Pi}]]
```

As a result, I have obtained this:

```
Probability[cosx1-cosx2≤5,{x1,x2}UniformDistribution[{0,2π}]]
```

That is not a numerical result. Am I doing something wrong in the line of code or it is not possible to obtain a precise result of the probability or a function of `x` in the generic case?

Comment: Just a two comments on your code:  (1) The probability is 1 for your first line of code as the sum of two cosines will never be bigger than 2, (2) You should use lowercase letters for variables.

Comment: Take a look at [`Distributed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Distributed.html) as I think that's what you meant with "`~`".

Answer (score 10):

The correct syntax for a multivariate [`UniformDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UniformDistribution.html) is

```
dist = UniformDistribution[{{0, 2*Pi}, {0, 2*Pi}}];
```

Note that [`Distributed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Distributed.html) is `\[Distributed]`

```
Probability[Cos[X1] + Cos[X2] <= 5, {X1, X2} \[Distributed] dist]

(*  1  *)
```

Alternatively, you could write

```
Probability[Cos[X1] + Cos[X2] <= 5, {
  X1 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 2*Pi}],
  X2 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 2*Pi}]}]

(*  1  *)
```

A probability of `1` is as expected since

```
FunctionRange[Cos[X1] + Cos[X2], {X1, X2}, y, Reals] // Quiet

(*  -2. <= y <= 2.  *)
```

**EDIT:**

```
prob[val_?NumericQ] := NProbability[Cos[X1] + Cos[X2] <= val,
   {X1, X2} \[Distributed] dist];

Plot[prob[val], {val, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I know that the function range will be between -2 and 2. Do you know if there is the possibility to compute the probability for a generic value `y` such that: f(y) = P[cos(x1)+cos(x2)<=y]? Instead of compute it for a precise value.

Comment: fwiw `Probability` will give an analytic result in terms of a parameter for the single variable case: `Probability[
 Cos[X1] <= a, {X1 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 2*Pi}]}]`

Comment: Again, thank you for your edit. Before, I didn't ask you precisely. Is is also possible with Mathematica to obtain a close-form expression of the probability as a function of `y`. Thus, a function of the plot you have just added?

Comment: Having played with this a bit I'm pretty well convinced there is not a closed form expression to be had, at least using the direct procedure `Probability` uses. You might want to try math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a numerical solution for 0.5 (rather than 5):

```
d = TransformedDistribution[Cos[x1] + Cos[x2], 
    {x1 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 2 π}], 
     x2 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 2 π}]}];

NProbability[z < 0.5, z \[Distributed] d]
(* 0.6916875929659185 *)
```

***Update***

I have not found an explicit formula but note that a numerical solution can be made as accurate as desired.  An alternative is using integration over a region.  Below is a comparison of 3 approaches:

```
z0 = 1.9;
d = TransformedDistribution[Cos[x1] + Cos[x2], {x1 , x2} \[Distributed] 
    UniformDistribution[{{0, 2 π}, {0, 2 π}}]];
Timing[NProbability[z < z0, z \[Distributed] d]]
(* {0.3432022,0.983881258047714} *)

Timing[NIntegrate[If[Cos[2 π x1] + Cos[2 π x2] <= z0, 1, 0], {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}]]
(* {0.2964019,0.983881258047714} *)

Timing[NIntegrate[4 If[Cos[2 π x1] + Cos[2 π x2] <= z0, 1, 0], {x1, 1/2, 1}, {x2, 1/2, 1}]]
(* {0.2028013,0.9838812580477139} *)
```

Comment: Is it possible to obtain a function of a parameter `y` such that: `f(y) = P[cos(x1)+cos(x2)<=y]`? Instead of compute a precise value.

Comment: Maybe.   Someone else looking at this might know way or the other.  You could certainly develop a large table of values of the probability for $-2 \le y \le 2$.

Answer (score 4):

Working toward a closed form solution:

```
g[a_] := NProbability[Cos[X1] + Cos[X2] <= a,
  {X1 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 2*Pi}],
   X2 \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 2*Pi}]}]
```

Following the definitions given in the documentation for `Probability` this reduces to:

```
f[a_] :=
 Piecewise[{{1, a >= 0}, {(Pi - ArcCos[1 + a])/Pi, -2 < a < 0}}, 0] -
  NIntegrate[
    ArcCos[a - Cos[X2]] Boole[-1 < a - Cos[X2] < 1], {X2, 0, 2 Pi}]/(2 Pi^2)
```

Sorry to skip a bunch of steps, but it's straightforward...

```
Plot[{f[a], g[a]}, {a, -2, 2},
 PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Red}, {Thin, Black}}]
```

[image]

That last `NIntegrate` I think can't be done in closed form. (The second form is considerably faster though, so perhaps it is useful.)

Answer (score 4):

Just a "simulation" approach. Note that Mma  has little trouble generative samples from the `TransformedDistribution`.

```
td = TransformedDistribution[
  Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, y} \[Distributed] 
   UniformDistribution[Table[{0, 2 Pi}, 2]]]
rv = RandomVariate[td, 100000];
ecdf = EmpiricalDistribution[rv];
is = 300;
Row[{Histogram[rv, Automatic, "CDF", Frame -> True, ImageSize -> is],
  Plot[CDF[ecdf, x], {x, -2, 2}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> is],
  ListPlot[
   Table[NProbability[u < t, u \[Distributed] td], {t, -2, 2, 0.1}], 
   Frame -> True, ImageSize -> is],
  Plot[Evaluate[NProbability[u < t, u \[Distributed] td]], {t, -2, 2},
    Frame -> True, ImageSize -> is]}]
```

[image]

**Note**

I edited the original code to deal with an issue that became clarified after discussion with Jim Baldwin. In using `UniformDistribution[2]` as the multivariate for `TranformedDistribution` with transform: `Cos[2 Pi x]+ Cos[2 Pi y]`, the distribution could be sampled but the transformed distribution object was problematic (no formal x's) and `NProbability` was problematic.

Comment: Very good.  Did you mean "Probability" has issues rather than "NProbability" ?

Comment: @JimBaldwin I just meant the application of `NProbability` and `CDF` on the transformed distribution yield "crazy" values...I just didn't have the time to drill down to understand why. Just thought I'd add these to the others. :) ( I voted for the other answers as they all work )

Comment: Sorry I'm being thick.  I don't see any issues with `NProbability` in any of the answers.

Comment: @JimBaldwin no, no, no you are not being thick! I am not explaining myself well enough.  I hope [this](http://imgur.com/a/BKu1M)  illustrates. You might be able to help me with my *thickness*...I just took the path of least thought:)

Comment: OK.  From that example in your comment I take it you mean that `NProbability` can have issues - but maybe not for this particular distribution.  Is there a link that defines `td`? (again, in the example you give in the comment)

Comment: @JimBaldwin `td` is as in the code of my answer. I just re-ran and added the commands you saw, Still useful to have this discussion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48534/discussion-between-jim-baldwin-and-ubpdqn).